Using EF Core ChangeTracker for Blazor Web App (Serverside)
I have a webshop running in a Blazor Web App application (server side). Everything works perfectly locally. But as soon as the application is online, it crashes every few days. This means that when I call up the application, the page loads indefinitely and I can't see any page. I then have to stop the whole application and restart it. Sometimes it works for a few days, but sometimes only for a few hours. I have noticed from the logs that this problem often occurs when the page is crawled.
I've been trying to get to the bottom of the problem for a while now. One possibility for the problem is EF Core. I have two scoped services that initialize an instance of EF Core DbContext and then discard it in the Dispose() function. Those services only track one entity with a few subentites, and changes to those entities can only be made through the corresponding service.
I know that a DbContext should only be kept as short as possible (as stated here), but I would also like to use the ChangeTracking of EF Core (UnitOfWork concept). Is there a way to do this? And can this problem really be the cause of the crashes? If not, what else could be the cause?
I found user with similar problems, but none of the solutions fixed my problem.

Server Issue
Disposing Issue


Change tracking utilizes a cache but it is meant solely for reference resolving, not keeping data cached between requests/operations. Since Blazor server-side keeps sessions open between requests you will want to utilize an explicit lifetime scope for how long a DbContext is kept alive. Having just two points where a DbContext is instantiated and disposed sounds like an issue of a DbContext being kept alive too long. Given enough time EF's tracking cache will track an entire database which is a performance, resource, and stale data concern.

Thank you very much for your reply. In this specific DbContext there is just one entity tracked (the cart with the cart items), and all changes which are made are beeing made through this CartService. Could this still lead to performance issues? Is there another way to use a change tracker or do I have to update the whole entity? (e.g. DbContextUpdate(this.Cart).

Are you using a single DbContext or the DbContextFactory [It's not clear from your question]?

You are right. I‘m using a DBFactory which gets injected into the service, where I than create a single instance of a DBContext and save it in a global class variable. The class has a Dispose method where the DBContext gets disposed.

That defeats the object of using a factory.  They should be short lived [normally less that a second or two] and transactional.  You're problems are almost certainly a consequence of what you're doing with the context.
